# how to fill a jlist without compiler warning

Tags: java, swing, generics, jlist

I've looked at several dozen different posts on this topic and still have not found a solution. I am trying to modify this code so that it no longer produces a compiler warning:

> warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setListData(Vector) as a member of the raw type JList
>               jlistCoilModels.setListData(coilModelList);   where E is a type-variable:
>       E extends Object declared in class JList

All the posts I've read talk about generics vs raw, and type conversion. (I read the Oracle documentation) I get that, I just don't have a clue how to fix this so that it no longer produces a compiler warning. Leaving out the boring details, here are the lines of code I'm working with.

```
Vector<String> coilModelList = new Vector<>();
while (rset08.next()) {
    coilModelList.add(rset08.getString("CoildModelNumber"));
}
jlistCoilModels.setListData(coilModelList);
```

Thanks for taking the time to respond.

EDIT: 2015-07-07 
Ok, hopefully this will take this thread off HOLD. Here is the entire code I have in a test application. The compiler is even issuing warnings for the code sections that were generated automatically by NetBeans. I cannot change the auto-generated sections of this code. I am still no closer to understanding the proper way to use a JList so as to avoid the compiler warnings. Even the tutorials I've found online all produce the same result. I know there is something really important for me to learn here. I'm seriously seeking to understand the best practices of using the JList.

```
package jlist.example;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

/**
 *
 * @author petehahn
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList(); //this line produces a warning
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 166, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(97, 97, 97)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap(176, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(12, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 228, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(19, 19, 19))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String[] filler = {"Filler1", "Filler2", "Filler3", "Filler4", "Filler5"};
        DefaultListModel<String> fillerListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < filler.length - 1; i++) {
            fillerListModel.addElement(filler[i]);
        }
        jList1.setModel(fillerListModel);// this line produces a warning

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JList jList1;// this line produces a warning
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Show the declaration for `jlistCoilModels`, which I'm betting is just `JList` and not `JList<String>`.

Comment: You're leaving out too much code, and we'll need to see more. Which line specifically causes the warning?

Comment: It's also easier to use a `ListModel` IMHO

Comment: If you have a look at the method decleration; [`setListData(Vector<? extends E> listData)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setListData(java.util.Vector)), you will see it's expecting a `Vector` of objects which extend from `E`.  `E` is defined by the [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) class itself, `JList<E>`, when you declare your variable, you need to define the constraints as well. Perhaps you should also have a look at [Generics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: The JList object (jlistCoilModels) was created by dropping it onto the GUI. The code for it was automatically generated. So do I need to check that generated code, and make sure it declares it using "JList<String>"?

Comment: The line which causes the compiler warning is the very last line I presented.

Comment: Well, it shows the warning for the variable we've been talking about, so it should be obvious where the problem lies, no?

Comment: I've already read through some of the Generics Trail, thanks for offering that. But it just didn't help me understand this. I must be having a major brain block because I'm just not getting it. What need to be modified and how? Maybe once I see that I will understand it.

Comment: I sure wish this were as obvious to me as everyone else. Here is the statement under initComponents: jlistCoilModels = new javax.swing.JList(); and here it is under variable declarations: private javax.swing.JList jlistCoilModels;  These are in areas that are greyed out and cannot be modified.

Comment: Did you read *the first comment*? Look at the declaration.

Comment: Stop using a GUI builder and code the GUI by hand.  That way you can modify any of the GUI code.

Comment: Thanks for that tip Gilbert Le Blanc. Unfortunately I have inherited a large application from someone else and I'm working to bring it up to enterprise level standards. So what's done is done.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the valuable answers chrylis and MadProgrammer. Only think lacking was how to acheive that in my current project environment. Well I found that I can edit the .java files in a text editing program (I used Sublime Text). Once I updated the following lines:

FROM

```
  jList1 = new javax.swing.JList(); 
  private javax.swing.JList jList1;
```

TO

```
  jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>(); 
  private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
```

I then imported the modified .java file back into my project and compiled the file. No more compiler warnings were issued for the jList1 object. So now I have a workable solution for updating the entire project.

Edit: 7/20/2015
Found an even better solution. This link describes the fix is to simply adjust the type parameter via the properties in NetBeans. 
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=200381
Select the component/bean.
Switch to Code section in Properties window.
Modify 'Type Parameters' property.